# Kitchen Installation new build: How long after heat goes on?

Tags: kitchens, heating, plaster, humidity, new-home

**In Short**

Our kitchen suppliers have told us that the kitchen should only go in 6-8 weeks after the heat has been turned on in our new build. Their concern is how dry the house is, I assume the issue they're talking about (in technical terms) is relative humidity? Would I be right in saying as long as we are achieving a reading of 50% or less humidity-wise, there should be no issue?

The reason I ask is we're working off a deadline which will only allow us 5 1/2 weeks of lead time with the heating on otherwise the whole thing gets pushed back 1-2 months.

**TL;DR - A bit more background below**

House Area: 250m2
Construction Type: Concrete Block

Our floors have been poured 4 weeks ago:

- Upstairs: 50mm liquid screed
- Downstairs: 100mm sand and cement

The plastering was completed 5 weeks ago (gypsum all around and skim on ceilings)

I have been opening all the windows during the day and removing all condensation with a window vacuum before I close them up again at night.

For the past week the house has been receiving heat at night via 2 x 2.5kw heaters running for 8 hours.

The heating is to be provided by a heat pump (air to water) and distributed via underfloor heating, we also have a heat recovery system which should take some moisture out.

**Recommendations**

We've be told not to install dehumidifiers as it will crack the plaster, so is there anything else we should be trying or anything that we *are* doing and should stop?

Another suggestion was to isolate the heat to the kitchen by taping up openings to other rooms? My thinking was the moisture would be drawn from other rooms once these temp barriers were removed?